# Restarting Server by IIS Manager

Tags: iis, server, iis-7

I have removed a Role from Server Manager Console  and after that it is aking for restarting the server. Can i restart the server by IIS Manager (Restart action) after removing a role from Server Manager of the same server?
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

You can't restart the machine from iis manager, you can obviously restart the webserver from the GUI.

Of course if you have an elevated CLI you can do either:

```
iisreset
```

Or

```
shutdown -r -t 60
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.. My query is that would i have to restart the machine itself after removing the role from Server Manager ?

Comment: Yes, as the machine is saying, it requires a restart to take effect.